# Table ID Indicies not resetting in Postgresql Databse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I've just made the switch from SQLite to Postgresql for my rails app. Strangely the indices of my models continue to increment outside of my sandbox. So for instance:

```
rails c -s
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
=> #<User id: 1>
^D
(0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
rails c -s
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
=> #<User id: 2>
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
=> #<User id: 3>
```

Notice how the user id index continues to increment from 1 despite exiting from my sandbox. Other than the initial setup for creating a postgresql db, I haven't customized anything outside the ordinary (that I'm aware of). As far as gems, I'm using `rails (5.0.0)` (though tested on Rails 4 with no avail) and `pg (0.18.4)`. What's going on?

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: sample_user
  password: secret
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_test
```

Comment: re-using ids is generally bad idea anyways, and unless rails resets the increment in postgres when you exit your sandbox, postgres will just keep the last generated id on file and go from there. which is how it should be.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. Up until now I thought I had done something wrong in the my setup. I'm curious though, why is it a bad idea to re-use IDs?

Comment: contrived/simple example? consider a foreign key situation where cascaded deletes aren't performed, and some child records are left hanging around. you re-use an id, and now suddenly this new record has a bunch of children attached to it that probably shouldn't be. e.g. "patient #37" gets deleted, and the new patient #37 suddenly has 3 kids , a screaming case of crotch rot, and a whopping big medical bill, even though they only came in for a bandaid.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense. Appreciate the help. If you'd like to make this into an answer, feel free. More than happy to mark it as correct.